# Can a monster split its move action?

Tags: descent

Can a monster, similar to a hero, move 2 spaces, execute another action, like attack, or open a door, and move 2 spaces again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** From p. 8 of the [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/descent-second-ed/support/DJ01_Rulebook_ENG.pdf):

"Monsters follow the same movement rules as heroes when moving except that monsters cannot suffer fatigue to receive additional movement points."

In case you're still not convinced, p. 3 of the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/descent-second-ed/support/Descent%20Second%20Edition%20FAQ.pdf) specifically calls out "When a large monster interrupts its movement to perform an action" as part of a question referring to large monster movement.